# Yii2: how to use an attribute with comma-sep. list of values in checkboxList()

Tags: php, yii2, checkboxlist

I have an attribute where the database value is eg. `cash,creditcard,paypal`. On a form this of course needs to render as a checkbox for each option, so I assume I need to do this:

```php
echo $form->field($model, 'payment_options')
    ->checkboxList(['cash' => 'Cash', 'creditcard' => 'Credit Card', 'paypal' => 'PayPal', 'bitcoin' => 'Bitcoin']);
```

But none of the checkboxes are checked by default. How do I instruct Yii in splitting up (explode) the value by comma? and, I presume, concatenating (implode) again before inserting back into the database?

In the [`each` validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#each) I saw something about *array attributes* but I find no other info about how to deal with those...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this to be the best and most organized way of doing it.

Create a [behavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html) (eg. create the file `ArrayAttributes.php` in `components` folder and set `namespace app\components;`):

```php
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\base\Behavior;

/**
 * For handling array attributes, being a comma-separated list of values in the database
 * Additional feature is handling of JSON strings, eg.: {"gender":"req","birthdate":"hide","addr":"req","zip":"req","city":"req","state":"opt"}
 */

class ArrayAttributesBehavior extends Behavior {

    public $attributes = [];
    public $separator = ',';
    public $jsonAttributes = [];

    public function events() {
        return [
            ActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_FIND => 'toArrays',
            ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE => 'toArrays',
            ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'toStrings',
            ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'toStrings',
        ];
    }

    public function toArrays($event) {
        foreach ($this->attributes as $attribute) {
            if ($this->owner->$attribute) {
                $this->owner->$attribute = explode($this->separator, $this->owner->$attribute);
            } else {
                $this->owner->$attribute = [];
            }
        }

        foreach ($this->jsonAttributes as $attribute) {
            if (is_string($this->owner->$attribute)) {
                $this->owner->$attribute = json_decode($this->owner->$attribute, true);
            }
        }
    }

    public function toStrings($event) {
        foreach ($this->attributes as $attribute) {
            if (is_array($this->owner->$attribute)) {
                $this->owner->$attribute = implode($this->separator, $this->owner->$attribute);
            }
        }

        foreach ($this->jsonAttributes as $attribute) {
            if (!is_string($this->owner->$attribute)) {
                $this->owner->$attribute = json_encode($this->owner->$attribute);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then just configure it in the model:

```
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        [
            'class' => \your\namespace\ArrayAttributesBehavior::className(),
            'attributes' => ['payment_options'],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Then just keep in mind that these attributes are arrays when you make your forms, validation, etc.